# allowRotation in SceneKit?

Tags: ios8, scenekit

How can I disallow rotation of a node in SceneKit?

For ex., I want a model (cone) to be dynamic, jumping and flying, but always vertically oriented?

I tried fix it like in apple's vehicle demo, it is bad solution. Also I tried below code, but model just slowly and glitchy falls down

```
﻿- (void)renderer:(id<SCNSceneRenderer>)aRenderer didSimulatePhysicsAtTime:(NSTimeInterval)time{
    _node.rotation = SCNVector4Make(0, 0, 0, 0);
    //[_node.physicsBody resetTransform]; // - tried this too
}
```

...and finally I did not find any "allowRotation=NO" in scenekit manuals.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of a Boolean `allowsRotation` flag like in SpriteKit, SceneKit lets you choose which directions a body is allowed to rotate in and by how much. See the [`angularVelocityFactor`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNPhysicsBody_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SCNPhysicsBody/angularVelocityFactor) property.

This is probably a better idea than toggling the mass between different values — that approach looks like it could be unintended behavior, so you might not want to rely on it.

Comment: toggling mass is just kidding. angularVelocityFactor works well, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mix physics simulation and *manual* transforms, make sure to use a "kinematicBody" and not a "dynamicBody".

Answer (score 0):

Ahaha, I found some bug solving this problem (but this is a bug, so it is weird)

1. create node
2. set mass=1
3. add node to scene
4. set mass=0  - this makes it static and unmovable, but...
5. set mass=1 - this makes it dynamic, jumping and falling but **with fixed rotation!**

iOS 8.0.2 iPad mini

Answer (score -1):

Simple solution:

node.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false